# marge widget in PyQt4 Python

Tags: python, pyqt4

how can i marge **IP Address list** and the **combo box** to the top?i already try using **setAlignment** but the code is doesn't working?

*Result i got*

[image]

*Result i need like this*

[image: the result like this]

**my code**

```
layout = QGridLayout(window)
layout.addLayout(sublayout,0,0)
layout.addWidget(line,0,1)
layout.addLayout(sublayout2,0,2)
```

what method should i add in `layout` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `QVBoxLayout.addStretch` method:

```
sublayout2 = QVBoxLayout()
sublayout2.addWidget(lb3)
sublayout2.addWidget(combobox_ip_list)
sublayout2.addStretch(1)
```